# How to add custom information (ex. title of event) to form submission

Tags: php, wordpress, events, twitter-bootstrap-3

**Situation**: 
I'm building a website on Bootstrap 3.0, and it contains a section with upcoming events. If a user wants to attend, they can do that by clicking on the event. Now a modal appears with name, e-mail and event title input fields. The e-mail goes to me so I know who's coming for what. This is the html for a single event:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="event-left">
      <div class="event-date">
         <h1>15 mrt</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="event-title">
         <p>Random event title</p>
      </div>
      <a class="cta-button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-lg"></i></a>
      <div class="event-text">
         <p>Random event description</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Question**: How can I code this, so it automatically adds the title of an event to the e-mail by clicking on the event? I don't want users to type the event title manually when the modal appears. I'm also open for better ways to do this.

*current process*:
visitor clicks on event > fills in name, e-mail and event title > submits form

*future process*:
visitor clicks on event > fills in name, email > submits form

**Info**:
I'll be using Wordpress as CMS.

Comment: Use hidden element to keep your event id or name which is not seen to user. When user click submit, you can get it from hidden field

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply! That's interesting, but how does the hidden field know which event title it's adding to the e-mail? I think I need php or javascript code to do this.

Comment: How do you load your event to page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are working with a custom post type for your events.

Yes, you will need to populate the hidden field yourself. On the single template, in the form markup, you can output the title of the event as the value of the hidden field by using the wordpress function the_title(). You could also do it with javascript, but this is exactly the kind of situation wordpress templates and PHP are made for.

You might also think about grabbing the event post id for the event using the_ID(). Two events can easily have the same title, but will never have the same post id.

```
<form id="your_form" action="/" method="GET">  
  <input type="hidden" name="hidden_info_event_title" value="<?php the_title() ?>" >
  <input type="hidden" name="hidden_info_event_id" value="<?php the_ID() ?>" >
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

It is worth noting that even though named "hidden field", the values are easily accessible to anyone using your form, and after the page loads and your PHP is output, they can be changed to anything very easily and then submitted. So if you have any restrictions on what events are shown to what users, someone can potentially just replace the title in their form with an event they shouldn't be able to rsvp for, but you'd never know that from the email you receive. But that's a whole other question.

Comment: If you are working on events within a wordpress theme, you should absolutely check out wordpress custom posts, and the functions provided by the CMS to get the info, display it, etc. You may have a good reason not to work with them, but that's kind of the whole point of using the CMS.